# Azure AD B2C with Microsoft account and Sign in user

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am getting this error when configuring an asp.net core app to use Azure AD B2C authentication with Microsoft Account as external identity provider.

AADSTS70000121: The passed grant is from a personal Microsoft account and is required to be sent to the /consumers or /common endpoint.

As per my findings on SO and Microsoft documentation on the same, it points to use following as authority
in appsettings.json:

"Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",

The common endpoint is suggested by Azure AD b2c
documentation when you use Microsof Account as an identity provider.

While registering an application in Azure AD b2c tenant, I use following as Supported account types:

Accounts in any identity provider or organizational directory (for authenticating users with user flows)

So seems all is configured properly but still error suggest that I am not using common endpoint which in fact I am using it.

Links I followed:

[How to acces AzureRM with a AzureAD Multi-Tenant App using personal Microsoft account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57816117/how-to-acces-azurerm-with-a-azuread-multi-tenant-app-using-personal-microsoft-ac)

[Error getting SAML Metadata for Azure AD B2C Policy - AADB2C90022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54211656/error-getting-saml-metadata-for-azure-ad-b2c-policy-aadb2c90022)

Comment: if you use User Flows you need to use the token endpoint from the user flow, open the user flow link in a browser and copy the token endpoint and request the token from that endpoint

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-microsoft-account?pivots=b2c-user-flow